# How to use match against with 4 or less characters on shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building search engine for jobs and I've used match against but I have problem when I search with 'php', 'hr', 'IT'.

there are no results because I can't change `ft_min_word_len` variable on shared hosting , but my client tells me that he know others companies use same queries with match against  on shared hosting and it works !, so what is the solution now ?
Thanks

Comment: The other shared hosting companies may use lower min word length limit. There is no way to get around this limitation with fulltext search. Yo may use simple or extended pattern matching, but those may not use indexes. But the best way would be to extract the keywords / experiences from a cv to a separate table and do the search on that, not on the free text.

Comment: @Shadow please explain that 'But the best way would be to extract the keywords / experiences from a cv to a separate table and do the search on that, not on the free text'

Answer (score -1):

@Shadow pointed out that `ft_min_word_len` is MySQL server-wide setting. Some shared hosting companies will say *yes* when you ask for a change to that variable, and others will say *no.*  The worst ones will say *huh?*  Avoid those companies.

So your first task is to find out which companies say *yes.* Can you use one of those companies? If so, go do it.

If that doesn't work, you could consider moving your application to a virtual machine provider like Amazon Web Services, and installing your own MySQL server instance. It's a little more trouble, but you can control things.

If that doesn't work, and you must be able to search for short words, you'll need to populate your own short word table and search it with non-`FULLTEXT` SQL filtering.

To explain this in detail is beyond the scope of a SO answer. But here's the outline.

1. create a `shortwords` table containing two columns, `item_id` and `word`. `item_id` is a FK to another table containing your text items.  `word` is a `VARCHAR(6)` column. The primary key of this table can be a composite of both columns, that is, `(word, item_id)`.
2. populate that table by writing a php program to process each bit of text in your text items.  It must `explode` the text strings into words, then `INSERT` each short word into your `shortwords` table with the item_id. value.
3. When you search for short words do this sort of query.

   ```
      SELECT item.text
        FROM item
        JOIN shortwords ON item.item_id = shortwords.item_id
       WHERE shortwords.word = 'php'
          OR shortwords.word = 'it'
          OR shortwords.word = 'hr'
   ```

Look, this is an outline of the solution to your short word problem. It is going to take quite a bit of programming, *by you*, to get this working. Please don't ask SO to do this programming for you.

Comment: A shared hosting company with shared mysql server will never-ever agree to change the min word length for fulltext indexes because all fulltext indexes need to be rebuilt after this change. If you are extracting any keywords from the CV, then why just the short ones and why not all of them? Why maintain 2 types of indexes? You would need to maintain the list of keywords and just associate them with the CVs.

Comment: It's a community wiki answer @Shadow -- go ahead and edit it.

Comment: Why was this question turned into a community wiki?